# Búsqueda Interna: A. Búsquedas y modificaciones en un arreglo

Tags: c++, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

Descripción
Dado un arreglo de N enteros, escribe un programa que procese una secuencia de M comandos de los siguientes tipos:

EXISTE K: Determinar si el entero K existe o no en el arreglo.
CAMBIA_PARES: Sumar 3 a todos los elementos del arreglo que tengan un valor par.

Entrada
El entero N seguido de los N enteros del arreglo. Posteriormente, el entero M seguido de los M comandos a procesar. Puedes suponer que 0≤N, M≤10^(5) y que los elementos del arreglo están en el rango de 0 a 10^(9).

Salida
Para cada evento del tipo EXISTE, un 1 si el entero buscado existe en el arreglo y un 0 en caso contrario. Los valores impresos deben aparecer separados por espaciado en blanco.

La cuestión es que OmegaUp, me lo marca como Tiempo límite excedido (TLE), cuando la respuesta es correcta, ¿qué implementación podría hacer para que esto no suceda?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Función para determinar si un entero K existe en el arreglo
int existe(const vector<int>& arreglo, int k) {
    for (int num : arreglo) {
        if (num == k) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Función para sumar 3 a todos los elementos pares del arreglo
void cambiaPares(vector<int>& arreglo) {
    for (int& num : arreglo) {
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num += 3;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n; // Tamaño del arreglo
    vector<int> arreglo(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> arreglo[i]; // Leer los elementos del arreglo
    }

    cin >> m; // Número de comandos a procesar

    vector<int> resultados; // Almacenar resultados para imprimir después

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        string comando;
        cin >> comando;
        if (comando == "EXISTE") {
            int k;
            cin >> k; // Leer el entero a buscar
            resultados.push_back(existe(arreglo, k)); // Almacenar resultado para imprimir después
        } else if (comando == "CAMBIA_PARES") {
            cambiaPares(arreglo); // Sumar 3 a todos los elementos pares
        }
    }

    // Imprimir resultados
    for (int res : resultados) {
        cout << res << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para optimizar tu código te propondría 2 cambios, que puedes implementar cualquiera de ellos os los 2 a la vez:

1. Añadir un flag que indique si has llamado alguna vez a cambiaPares(). Esto es debido a que en cuanto llames a cambiaPares() por primera vez, todos los elementos ya serán impares, e invocarlo de nuevo será desperdiciar tiempo de porcesamiento iterando el arreglo, por lo que comprobando si esta seteado el flag llamaremos a la función o ignoraremos el comando.
2. Utilizar **set** en lugar de **vector**. Esto es debido a que un set es muchísimo más rápido a la hora de buscar si incluye un elemento concreto dentro de él

Comment: Entiendo, los cambios propuestos son bastante útiles para mejorar la eficiencia del programa y evitar el tiempo límite excedido.

1. Añadir un flag para indicar si se ha llamado alguna vez a cambiaPares().
2. Utilizar un conjunto (set) en lugar de un vector para almacenar los elementos del arreglo, ya que la búsqueda en un conjunto es más eficiente que en un vector.